# "Preference" window is abnormally displayed without buttons and boxes

Tags: display

The preference interface is displayed abnormally. Although buttons and check boxes are not displayed, they can be operated. Anyone know why? thank you!

(Mathmatica 12.3, Windows 10)

[image]

Comment: Did you try restarting Mathematica/the computer?

Comment: @LukasLang I tried many times...

Comment: Could be related to [this](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2152918) issue with 12.3 on some Windows 10 systems. See the workaround given by Ian Hojnicki.

Comment: @hmilton thank you, `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {RenderingOptions, "PreferredGPU"}] = "Software"` solved the problem!